# Product of adjacency matrices

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering if there was any meaningful interpertation of the product of two $n\times n$ adjacency matrices of two distinct graphs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The story extends to non-square matrices. Consider a collection $A$ of $a$ vertices, another collection $B$ of $b$ vertices, and a collection of directed edges from the first collection to the second (in other words, a bipartite graph, but where we choose explicitly a $2$-coloring of the vertices). We can organize this data into a $b \times a$ matrix whose entries describe the number of edges from a vertex in the first collection to a vertex in the second.

Now consider a third collection $C$ of $c$ vertices and some directed edges from vertices in $B$ to vertices in $C$. We can organize this data into a $c \times b$ matrix as above.

Then the product of the two matrices above is a $c \times a$ matrix describing how to get from vertices in $A$ to vertices in $C$ by following edges that go through $B$.

This idea is the basis of a combinatorial approach to linear algebra which is described, for example, in Brualdi and Cvetkovic's [A combinatorial approach to matrix theory and its applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=pwx6t8QfZU8C&dq=brualdi+combinatorial+linear+algebra&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

---

For the initiated, the above admits the following nice interpretation: we have described composition of morphisms of a particularly nice [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). In fact, if I'm not mistaken, it's the free category with finite [biproducts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biproduct) on one object.

Comment: Did you buy or download a pirate copy? ;)

Answer (score 33):

Suppose $A$ is the adjacency matrix of graph $G_1$ and $B$ the adjacency matrix of graph $G_2$, where we consider both $G_1$ and $G_2$ to have the same vertices $1,\ldots,n$.  Then $(AB)_{ij}$ is the number of ways to get from $i$ to $j$ by going first along an edge of $G_1$ and then along an edge of $G_2$.

Comment: These sorts of results seem too good to be true.

Answer (score 1):

The dot product of the adjacency matrix with itself is a measure of similarity between nodes. For instance take the non-symmetric directed adjacency matrix A =

```
1, 0, 1, 0
0, 1, 0, 1
1, 0, 0, 0
1, 0, 1, 0
```

then the dot of $A^T$A (gram matrix) gives the un-normalized similarity between column i and column j which is the symmetric matrix:

```
3, 0, 2, 0
0, 1, 0, 1
2, 0, 2, 0
0, 1, 0, 1
```

This is much like the gram matrix of a linear kernel in an SVM. An alternate version of the kernel is the RBF kernel. The RBF kernel is simply a measure of similarity between two datapoints that can be looked up in the nxn matrix. Likewise, so is the linear kernel.

A Gram matrix is simply the dot of its transpose and itself.

Now say you have matrix B which is also a non-symmetric directed adjacency matrix. B =

```
1, 0, 1, 0
1, 0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0, 0
1, 0, 0, 1
```

So $A^T$B is a non-symmetric matrix:

```
3, 0, 1, 1
1, 0, 0, 0
2, 0, 1, 1
1, 0, 0, 0
```

Matrix A col i and matrix B col j are proportionately similar according to the above matrix. Thus the dot product of transpose of the first matrix to the second matrix is a measure of similarity of nodes characterized by their edges.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.